# access denied on nginx and php

Tags: php, nginx

Using nginx web server and php. nginx is working, I see 'Welcome to nginx!' but I get 'access denied' when trying to access a php page. I also installed php-fastcgi.

Here is my nginx default conf:

```
# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

# proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
#}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
   # fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny  all;
}
```

I activited `security.limit_extensions = .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .html` and `listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock` in /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf and `cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0` in /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

I restarted nginx and php5-fpm.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do like this where you have your secondary location

```
location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;  

        root /path/to/your/www;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO         $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    }
```

These 2 parameters are the magic sauce:

```
fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO         $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Comment: I still have the problem, does it have to do with this line I got: `fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;`? In my case I am using CentOS 7, PHP 7.2 and Nginx 1.14. I have the server in a virtual box, accessible in browser through IP address: 192.168.x.x

Answer (score 9):

In the event that you are trying to use NGINX to parse HTML as PHP and you are getting an `Access denied` error, you need to change a PHP configuration setting.

On Ubuntu 16, the file you need to update is in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`.

Go to the line where it says `;security.limit_extensions = .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .php7`

Replace that with this `security.limit_extensions = .php .html`. Notice that the leading semi-colon has been removed.

Then restart PHP `sudo systemctl restart php7.0-fpm`. The issue should be fixed.

For more information please see this more detailed guide: [Fix "access denied" error when parsing HTML as PHP with Nginx](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/nginx-php-html-access-denied/)

Comment: Thanks..! it worked for me for Accecss Denied .html files.

Answer (score 2):

I know some possible scenarios when nginx and php cannot access files:

1. Most likely `php-fpm` process is run by user that does not have read permission on corresponding .php files.
   This gives plain error `Access denied.`
2. `nginx` process does not have read and traverse permissions on `root` directory containing the sites files.
   This gives `403 Forbidden` error.
3. `php-fpm` process cannot traverse the absolute path to `root` directory.
   This gives `File not found` error.

Since author mentions, that problem appears only when accessing php files, I would say that first scenario applies here.

I believe the case is that `nginx` is run as one user and `php-fpm` as another, only the `php-fpm` user has been forgotten to give read access.

Comment: I changed user and group in /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf file and web folder's owner changed as same user but does not work i give same result. i send nginx error log( 2014/02/20 17:19:39 [error] 2989#0: *6 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Access to the script '/usr/share/nginx/html' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.10.125.16, server: localhost, request: "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "10.254.10.19" )

Comment: Does it happen if you disable security.limit_extensions?
Also did you restart php-fpm?

Answer (score 1):

Please check your fastcgi_params file and change it accordingly to this post
https://askubuntu.com/questions/164627/nginx-php-fpm-access-denied-error

I solved my problem by using the above method.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu and openSUSE, the access denied error could also be related to AppArmor. You can easily check this by running

```
sudo grep -i denied /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

If you get something like this, it's AppArmor:

type=AVC msg=audit(1678543274.258:837): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="php-fpm" name="/srv/www/htdocs/test.php" pid=31787 comm="php-fpm" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=487 ouid=1000

Besides that, the line "include fastcgi_params;" in the nginx.conf file should come *before* any fastcgi_param definitions so that these do not get overwritten by existing definitions in the included fastcgi_params file.