# Nginx error FastCGI sent in stderr: "Access to the script [folder] has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)"

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, nginx, webserver

I am trying to configure my webserver using Nginx and php-fpm
I have successfully configured before in my local computer and dev server, but not now in AWS.
The only difference is I installed Nginx from a source in production server

It gives an error like these in my /var/log/nginx/error.log

```
2014/03/11 11:09:19 [error] 11138#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Access to the script '/home/ambassador-portal/ambassador-api/web' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 202.62.16.225, server: brandapi.whatiwear.com, request: "GET /app_dev.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "brandapi.whatiwear.com", referrer: "http://brandapi.whatiwear.com/"
```

While the error log in php-fpm gives no error

Here is my nginx.conf

```
user  root;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
        include /usr/local/nginx/conf/sites-enabled/*.conf;
}
```

Here is my nginx_host.conf

```
server {
    server_name brandapi.whatiwear.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/brandapi_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/brandapi_error.log;
    root /home/ambassador-portal/ambassador-api/web;
    disable_symlinks off;
    autoindex on;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /app.php$uri?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.htaccess {
            deny all;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
            include /usr/local/nginx/conf/fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Here is my /etc/php5/fpm/conf/www.conf

```
; Start a new pool named 'www'.
[www]

listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1

user = ec2-user
group = ec2-user

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 35

slowlog = /var/log/php-fpm/www-slow.log

security.limit_extensions = .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .html .htm
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/5.5/www-error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
;php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 128M

; Set session path to a directory owned by process user
php_value[session.save_handler] = files
php_value[session.save_path] = /var/lib/php/5.5/session
```

I've read from [access denied on nginx and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21909860/access-denied-on-nginx-and-php) and try to chmod  and I've tried the solution from [Nginx 403 forbidden for all files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795350/nginx-403-forbidden-for-all-files) and here is my result

```
dr-xr-xr-x  root        root  /
drwxr-xr-x root        root  home
drwxr-xr-x ec2-user ec2-user ambassador-portal
drwxr-xr-x ec2-user ec2-user ambassador-api
drwxr-xr-x ec2-user ec2-user web
```

I turned the autoindex on just for seeing if my root directory is right, the weird thing is I can open all files except PHP files

You can see a live example at http://brandapi.whatiwear.com/

What is wrong with my webserver..?

Answer (score 5):

I removed these two configurations from the `nginx.conf` file.

```
fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO  $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
```

It works.

Comment: I am working on PHP5.5.9 with Docker and occurs the error too, It works by follow above tips.

Comment: My prestashop suddenly stopped running and this solution worked for me. But i'm not sure why

Answer (score -2):

The problem is in this line
(in your /etc/php5/fpm/conf/www.conf)

```
security.limit_extensions = .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .html .htm
```

Just add the extension `.pl` after `.htm`.

Cheers.

Comment: How does adding .pl would change anything here? That server seems to be running PHP not Perl.