# Nginx cannot serve css or js

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I have just started using Docker and have issues configuring the containers to serve the web pages properly. The issue is the following:

```
nginx2         | 2018/03/17 19:01:19 [error] 8#8: *8 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Access to the script '/var/www/sites/public/res/styles.css' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.21.0.1, server: , request: "GET /res/styles.css HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.21.0.3:9000", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:8080/"
nginx2         | 172.21.0.1 - - [17/Mar/2018:19:01:19 +0000] "GET /res/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 403 25 "http://localhost:8080/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

I have tried adding my own custom `php-fpm.conf` file to the container with the modified `security.limit_extensions` parameter as indicated [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/php-fpm-security-limit_extension-issue) but this causes the following error

```
php2           | [17-Mar-2018 19:49:31] ERROR: [/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf:1] value is NULL for a ZEND_INI_PARSER_ENTRY
php2           | [17-Mar-2018 19:49:31] ERROR: failed to load configuration file '/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf'
php2           | [17-Mar-2018 19:49:31] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
php2 exited with code 78
```

I have also seen other users get around this issue by including `cgi.fix_pathinfo=1` in `php.ini`. However, this did not fix the original problem.

If it is helpful, I have included my nginx configuration here

```
server{
    # listen 80 default_server;
    index index.php index.html;
    # server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/sites/public;
    location / {
        # root /var/www/sites/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }
    location ~ /res/ {
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass php2:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        #include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php2:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

I have also tried modifying the `www.conf` file as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22324964/nginx-error-fastcgi-sent-in-stderr-access-to-the-script-folder-has-been-deni) however there is no such `/etc/php*` path.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed by removing all entries for `security.limit_extensions =` in `/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`.

The reason I could not locate the file was because it did not exist it my `nginx2` container, but was located in my `php2` container. I was searching for it in my `php2` container. My understanding is that since the files are static, they are best served by nginx.